# Postgresql: How to write insert query using where clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, select, insert

Let say we have a table called `user` and it has `userId` column.

```
user
----
userId
```

we have another table called `Team` and it has 2 columns `userId` and `leadId`.

```
Team
----
userId
leadId
```

**condition 1:**
I want to insert data into Teams table and that values, should be in user table. In other words `userId` and `leadId` of `Teams` table should of `userId` of `user` table. Otherwise it throws an error that id does not exists in user table.

**condition 2:**
one more condition is `userId` and `leadId` can't be same. This is done by using if check.

here is my API code

```
router.post('/', checkToken, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { body } = req;
        const {
            userId,
            leadId
        } = body

        const dataToInsert = {
            userId,
            leadId
        }

        if (userId == leadId) {
            res.status(300).json({ error: "Lead id and user can't be same." })
        }
        else {
            const data = await db.Team.create(dataToInsert)

            res.status(200).json({
                data
            })
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error in inserting team lead", e)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Internal Server Error",
            status: false,
        })

    }
})

export default router;
```

Please help how to handle the **condition 1**.

**update:**
this is what i tried now

```
  const IdCount= await db.User.findAll({
            attributes: [[db.Sequelize.fn('count', db.Sequelize.col('id')), 'getIdCount']],
            where: { "id": userId && leadId }
        });
```

**output of IdCount:**

here is the output, the getIdCount value is 0 which is correct but it send me whole object, how i can get only getIdCount value?

```
[
  user {
    dataValues: { getIdCount: '0' },
    _previousDataValues: { getIdCount: '0' },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

Comment: So `leadId` or `teamId`? Please correct your post

Comment: corrected, it is a ```leadId```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure both users exist in the Users table (execute two queries against the Users table) and then insert a record into the `Teams` table.
It's better to use an explicit transaction to get both users and insert a record into Teams.

To get either you have a user in DB you can use `count`:

```js
const whereClause = userId ?  {
            where: {
                id: userId,
            }
} : {}
const userCount = await db.User.count({
            where: {
                id: userId
            }
})
const userExists = count === 1;
```

The same way you can check `leadId`

Comment: I want some hint how to do this, i update my question what i'm trying to do, please check that.

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: please check my updated question, help if u can their.

Comment: Why didn't you try `User.count`?

Comment: check my uploaded answer, i used count, thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, that works too. But please don't forget about using a transaction especially if you're planning to make several changes in DB at once

Answer (score 0):

here is what i have done, it giving me correct responses on all condtions

```
router.post('/admin/assign', checkToken, authorize('admin'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { body } = req;
        const {
            userId,
            leadId
        } = body

        const dataToInsert = {
            userId,
            leadId
        }
        const idCount = await db.User.count({ where: { [Op.or]: [{ id: userId }, { id: leadId }] } })

        if (userId == leadId) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Lead id and user can't be same." })

        }
        else if (idCount == 2) {
            const data = await db.Team.create(dataToInsert)

            res.status(200).json({
                data
            })
        }
        else {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "UserId or LeadId doesn't exist" })
        }



    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error in inserting team lead", e)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Internal Server Error",
            status: false,
        })

    }
})

export default router;
```